# Why is ShellExecuteEx not returning the process handle?

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt

I am trying to open an image with the following function:

```
HANDLE openFile(char *path){ // path = "C:\Users\Foo Bar\Code\Test\test.jpg"
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC ;
    info.hwnd = NULL;
    info.lpVerb = L"open";
    info.lpFile = utf8_toWchar(path);
    info.lpParameters = NULL;
    info.lpDirectory = NULL;
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    info.hInstApp = NULL;

    if (!ShellExecuteExW(&info)){
        System_printLastErrorString(); //never gets here
    }
    //free((void*)info.lpFile);
    CoUninitialize();

    return info.hProcess; //this is always NULL
}
```

The problem is that `info.hProcess` is always `NULL` despite the fact that the default image editing program is not open and is opened a bit later.

How do I fix this?

Side Note: I dont know if this is relevant, but the calling program is a Qt Application.

Comment: Not all executions result in the creation of a process. An inproc activation for example runs inside your process.

Comment: @RaymondChen that is clearly not what is happening in this case since a process is spawned a few seconds later.

Comment: The process was not created by ShellExecute. (Seeing as it was creates after ShellExecute already returned, and ShellExecute is not psychic.)

Comment: @RaymondChen no...but I think it simply created it in an asynchronous manner despite the flag, the question is why.

Comment: What process was launched? The standard picture viewer app runs inproc.

Comment: @RaymondChen it is run in dllhost.exe according to task manager

Comment: @RaymondChen the default command to open a jpg is `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1`

Comment: Ah, but if you look more closely, there is a `HKCR\jpegfile\shell\open\DropTarget:CLSID`. That says that this is an inproc handler. No process is created by `ShellExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling `CreateProcess` myself to the result of `AssocQueryString`. This gave me the handle I needed.